# Show length from all text

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$('.text').show().html().length="15";
```

```css
.text
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

</div>
```

Hello, 
is possible to show only 15 first characters from the all text ?

Comment: Trim and substring...

Comment: Like `$(".text").text((_,t)=>t.slice(0,15));` ?

Comment: You can wrap the remaining characters in a span/div that'is styled so as not to appear on the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) or [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method with a callback and get HTML string of length `15` using [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method.

```js
$('.text').show().html(function(_, oldHtml) {
  return oldHtml.slice(0, 15);
});
```

```css
.text {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to
  using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their
  infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

</div>
```

Comment: This is the only decent solution on this page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JavaScript function `substr` to find the first 15 characters as follows:

```js
var string=document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML;
var subs=string.substr(0,15);
document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML=subs;
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">hello world. this is a string to only show the first 15 characters of a string.</p>
```

Comment: This will work, but not scalable and not convenient.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
    var text=$(".text").html();
    var res =text.substr(0, 15);
    alert(res);
```

Comment: Will only do it for the first `.text`. Doesn't answer the question at all (doesn't write back).

Comment: Isn't this what he wanted?

Comment: You think OP wanted to take text from the page and show alert? I don't think so.

Comment: Not to alert .. it is just sample to show the result

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x= $('div.text').text();
var first15=x.substring(0, 15);
$(".text").html(first15);
```

```css
.text
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).

</div>
```

Comment: Will only do it for the first `.text` and damage all other `.text` on the page. Very bad.

Comment: @dfsq yea sure but thats not my problem i cant paint all this stuff here. i can not read his mind how many .text-s he will have

Comment: Of course, but you as a developer *must* think strategically (if you are good developer of course). In this case, your solution is pretty bad simply because it will only for the simplest case, which is fine in many cases, but not in this one, because making it 100% flexible is very little effort. That's why I said this is pretty bad solution, generally speaking. You don't need to read customer's mind, you just need to foresee next step (next, not 100 steps).

Comment: @dfsq bro, im begginer not pro like you and i just tried to help, if someone knows to give better answer go a head, we all love to learn something new and better, thats why we here. we all have to pass thousand of phases to learn something.

Comment: Of course, no offense, I just explained why your answer is not good. But again, you have upvote, which means that your answer was useful. And now you know what can be improved about your approach which I think is good too. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery to read and write the elements and regex to split the string, there is probably better solutions mentioned already, this is just another one

```
var text = $('.text').text(); //get the text from the div
var splitted = text.match(/.{1,15}/g); //split the text into groups of 15
var first15 = splitted[0]; //get the first group of elements; 
$('.text').text(first15); //place the desired text there
```

Comment: Will only do it for the first `.text`. Regex here is overkill. Will also overwrite all other `.text` with the first one. Also super bad solution.

Comment: what do you mean by first .text?

Comment: I mean if you have several containers with `.text` class after running your code all of them will have the same text.

Comment: oh you right , just did a close minded anwser!! didnt really count on a situation outside of the little code snippet the OP showed, but well that is something he needs to take into account, since his div didnt had any id or context i just used what i was presented with, but thanks for pointing it out tho